# Unable to extract text from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have Bootstrap Table that contains an edit button on each row. I've used a data formatter to make the pass the id of the record over with a data attribute that can be extracted when clicked. When I inspect the element in the console I can see the ID is in the dataset property, but when I try to get it out using element.dataset the console contains an error telling me that the dataset is undefined. It's frustrating because I can see it's there!

Here's my click event:

```
$(".job-edit").click(function(event) {
    var editModal = $("#jobEditModal");
    var clicked = $(event.target);
    var id = clicked.dataset.jobid;
    console.log(id);
    event.stopPropagation();
    //editModal.modal(); 
});
```

And the formatter that sets the button up:

```
job.editFormatter = function (value) {
    return "<button class='btn job-edit text-center' data-jobId='" + value + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i> Edit</button>";
}
```

So far I've tried replacing `.dataset` with `.getAttribute()`, but that didn't work either, I've also tried changing the casing of `jobid` to `jobId`, past that I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

Comment: try- `clicked.data('jobid')` or `clicked.attr('data-jobid')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because `clicked` is a jQuery object which has no `dataset` property.

To fix this you need to use the native element reference:

```
var id = e.target.dataset.jobid;
```

Alternatively, use the `data()` method of the jQuery object:

```
var id = clicked.data('jobid');
```

Comment: using `jobId` gived `id` as undefined in console . shouldn't this be `jobid`?

Comment: @Niladri you're right. It was my typing habit to capitalise the 'Id' :)

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `dataset` you can directly get the `jobid` by using `.data()` method of jquery like below.you are getting undefined value for dataset as the `clicked` variable is a jquery object which does not have a definition for `dataset`

```js
$(".job-edit").click(function(event) {
    var editModal = $("#jobEditModal");
    var id = $(this).data("jobid");
    console.log(id);
    event.stopPropagation();
    //editModal.modal(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn job-edit text-center' data-jobId='2'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i> Edit</button>
```